# Qt: Non ASCII characters in file names are replaced by '?'

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, character-encoding

I have to work on a very reduced System. It's based on Ubuntu but not installed with the Ubuntu installer. So they are only really necessary packages and configuration. QtCreator is installed and works.

When I try to create a file with a non ASCII character, the character is replaced by `?`. E.g.: `TestÄ.txt` will be named `Test?.txt`. But this only happens, when I use Qt functions. C++ standard library works.

Example:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <fstream>

int main(int, char *[])
{
    const char* fileName = "TestÄ.txt";
    qDebug() << fileName;

    {
        QFile f(fileName);
        f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        f.write("QFile Äößń\n");
    }

    {
        std::ofstream f;
        f.open(fileName, std::fstream::app);
        f << "std::ofstream Äößń\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There should be one file `TestÄ.txt` with two lines. But the first block creates the file `Test?.txt`. The second block works as expected. The content of the files is written correct.

Comment: If your source file is Latin1 encoded, you can try `QFile f(QString::fromLatin1(fileName));` Qt5 assumes `UTF-8` by default.

Comment: Try setting up the correct locale with `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")`.

Comment: If the problem isn't code, it could be the character encoding you are using for [names in the file system](https://serverfault.com/a/87087).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The systems locale was not set. I didn't realize it because someone added the configuration in the `.bashrc` so the locale was set in the terminal.

To fix it, I created the file `/etc/default/locale` with content:

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because by your compiler that does not know how to handle `Ä` in the source file.

You could try `"Test\xC3\x84.txt"` (or `u8"TestÄ.txt"` if you have C++17).

Also note that the `QFile` constructor will convert your char array to a QString. If you want to check how this goes you could add:

```
qDebug() << QString(fileName).toUtf8().toHex(); // Should print "54657374c3842e747874"
```

and check that you have `0xC384` for the `Ä`.